# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] when adding additional dependencies

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am managing my views using state (`ui.router`). However, adding additional dependencies to the module as below is causing the error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

which makes my states break.

```
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

And then I change the above to

```
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'angularGrid']);
```

to support the angular grid. When I add the 3rd dependency , angular throws the error. And then I changed the code as below

```
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap');
MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', ['angularGrid');
```

Yet not much luck and still getting the same error.

Is there anything that I am missing?

Error :

```
Failed to instantiate module angularGrid due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/nomod?p0=angu...
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:50196/Scripts/Angular/angular.min.js:6:416
    at http://localhost:50196/Scripts/Angular/angular.min.js:24:66
    at a (http://localhost:50196/Scripts/Angular/angular.min.js:23:109)
    at http://localhost:50196/Scripts/Angular/angular.min.js:23:352
    at http://localhost:50196/Scripts/Angular/angular.min.js:37:451
    at m (http://localhost:50196/Scripts/Angular/angular.min.js:7:322)
    at g (http://localhost:50196/Scripts/Angular/angular.min.js:37:229)
    at http://localhost:50196/Scripts/Angular/angular.min.js:37:398
    at m (http://localhost:50196/Scripts/Angular/angular.min.js:7:322
```

Comment: Read the error details carefully, it also tells you for which module it's failing... Tell us that module name

Comment: Edited the question. Looks like angularGrid is failing

Comment: Are you including angular grid javascript from the right place? Is it included after angular js? Check your browser dev tools for errors.

Comment: It means the js related to angulargrid is not loaded.. Check that

Comment: Also you tried to define angular module twice, don't do that.. It's just wrong.. You shouldn't do that

Comment: @entre .. Noted and the code is changed..

Comment: Thanks guys.. works fine now ...I added the javascript in the wrong place.

Comment: @AlanB posted my comment as answer.. please accept/upvote

Answer (score 0):

Try to include dependency for underscore.js

Answer (score 0):

as per the error the injector is not able to find module angulgarGrid. You need to load then angular-grid js in index.html.

also

```
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap');
MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', ['angularGrid');
```

you should define module once per application